# How to return a string to main function?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to write code to implement `strchr` function in c. But, I'm not able to return the string.

I have seen discussions on how to return string but I'm not getting desired output

```
const char* stchr(const char *,char);
int main()
{
    char *string[50],*p;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter a sentence\n");
    gets(string);
    printf("Enter the character from which sentence should be printed\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    p=stchr(string,ch);
    printf("\nThe sentence from %c is %s",ch,p);
}
const char* stchr(const char *string,char ch)
{
    int i=0,count=0;
    while(string[i]!='\0'&&count==0)
    {
        if(string[i++]==ch)
            count++;
    }
    if(count!=0)
    {
        char *temp[50];
        int size=(strlen(string)-i+1);
        strncpy(temp,string+i-1,size);
        temp[strlen(temp)+1]='\0';
        printf("%s",temp);
       return (char*)temp;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I should get the output similar to `strchr` function but output is as follows

```
Enter a sentence
i love cooking
Enter the character from which sentence should be printed
l
The sentence from l is (null)
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code. It will show you where your logic is wrong.

Comment: Learning how to debug is an important part of learning how to program.

Comment: Why are you doing all those things in the `stchr` function? All that `strchr` does it finding the `char` in question and then returning the address of that `char`. No need for this suspect dynamic memory routine. Unless your `strch` shouldn't actually be a `strchr` implementation and is supposed to do something else that you didn't mention.

Comment: 1) `string`, in main function is actually an array of char pointers (not a string). `char string[50];` is the correct declaration. 2) as someone mentioned above, your `strchr()` has a strange funtionallity: it counts the number of `ch` occurrencies in string and returns a brand new string instead of providing the address of `ch` first occurrency. 3) If you want a function returning a copy of the original string, you cant return the address of a local variable. It's contained in thaa stack, and it will be overwritten after the function return.

Comment: Don't use gets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: Except from the fact that `gets` should never be used, this code has TONS of warnings. Read them. They show what's wrong.

Comment: Why are you copying the string?  You just want to return a pointer to the correct location in the extant string.  eg `const char* stchr(const char *s,char ch) { while(*s && *s != ch) s+=1; return *s ? s : NULL; }`

Comment: Here is an implementation of strchr: https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:string.h:strchr

Comment: @WilliamPursell You should cast `s` upon return to avoid a warning. `return *s ? (char*)s : NULL;`

Comment: `strncpy(temp,string+i-1,size);` This does not make any sense. `size` is taken as length of the remaining string. Same what would be done by normal `strcpy` If you want to limit string to your buffer size, you should use the size of your destination buffer as limit.

Comment: I thought that `strchr` would just return the entire string from matched character... Now, I have realized that's not the case. It only returns the address of the first occurrence of character. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically only two real **errors** in your code, plus one line that, IMHO, should certainly be changed. Here are the errors, with the solutions:

(1) As noted in the comments, the line:

```c
char *string[50],*p;
```

is declaring `string` as an array of 50 character ***pointers***, whereas you just want an array of 50 characters. Use this, instead:

```c
char string[50], *p;
```

(2) There are two problems with the line:
char *temp[50];
First, as noted in (1), your are declaring an array of character pointers, not an array of characters. Second, as this is a locally-defined ('automatic') variable, it will be deleted when the function exits, so your `p` variable in `main` will point to some memory that has been deleted. To fix this, you can declare the (local) variable as `static`, which means it will remain fixed in memory (but see the added footnote on the use of `static` variables):

```c
static char temp[50];
```

Lastly, again as mentioned in the comments, you should ***not*** be using the `gets` function, as this is now obsolete (although some compilers still support it). Instead, you should use the `fgets` function, and use `stdin` as the 'source file':

```c
fgets(string, 49, stdin);/// gets()  has been removed! Here, 2nd argument is max length.
```

Another minor issue is your use of the `strlen` and `strncpy` functions. The former actually returns a value of type `size_t` (always an **unsigned** integral type) not `int` (always **signed**); the latter uses such a `size_t` type as its final argument. So, you should have this line, instead of what you currently have:

```c
size_t size = (strlen(string) - i + 1);
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

**EDIT: Potential Problem when using the `static` Solution**

As noted in the comments by **Basya**, the use of static data can cause issues that can be hard to track down when developing programs that have multiple threads: if two different threads try to access the data at the same time, you will get (at best) a "data race" and, more likely, difficult-to-trace unexpected behaviour. A better way, in such circumstances, is to dynamically allocate memory for the variable from the "heap," using the standard `malloc` function (defined in `<stdlib.h>` - be sure to `#include` this header):

```c
char* temp = malloc(50);
```

If you use this approach, be sure to release the memory when you're done with it, using the `free()` function. In your example, this would be at the end of `main`:

```c
free(p);
```

Comment: note that using a static array means the function is not thread safe.

Comment: @Basya Noted, but for this 'simple' `int main()` program, that will not be an issue. Of course, using `char *temp = malloc(50);` is safer (and actually better, IMHO), but I try to keep things uncomplicated for early-stage learners of the language. My suggestion will solve (and hopefully explain) the issue.

Comment: Fair, but I am concerned that someone might copy this and not realize its implications.

Comment: Cool.  That got you an upvote :-)  -- the rest of the answer is good information.

Comment: I didn't realize that my code has these silly mistakes and errors. Thanks for helping me realizing them...